# Почему один скрипт блокирует другой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При добавлении

```
<script src=\"jquery.1.6.2.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
```

На страницу сайта начинает работать капча motionCaptcha, но при добавлении

```
<script src=\"jquery-1.7.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
```

капча работать не хочет. Но последний скрипт нужен для всплывающего окна... Впрочем, он тоже не работает, хоть все и правильно переносил вроде, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться.
Это скрипт [всплывающего окна](http://nazz.me/simple-jquery-popup/), а это сама [страничка сайта](http://yalonsu.16mb.com/add.php)...
Условия добавления объявления выше и есть то всплывающее окно

Comment: да, кажется, происходит замена, и это мешает работе скрипта... что-нибудь поищу еще

Comment: А если Вам нужно будет еще плагин добавить, который потребует jquery 1.8.0, Вы его тоже подключите? Не занимайтесь ерундой. Учите javascript.

Comment: а что вы посоветуете в такой ситуации?

Answer (score 1):

А зачем такое использователь? Из README

> At the moment, it's just a proof-of-concept, (no IE support) but the
> next releases will see progressive enhancement and the ability to use
> this in production environments as a serious CAPTCHA alternative.
>
> Don't try to use MotionCAPTCHA v0.2 in production - watch and wait for the full release!

На github последние изменения были 4 года назад, plug-in никто не поддерживает. По всей видимости plug-in имеет совместистимость с jQuery 1.6 и меньше.

И най мой взгляд Captch'у делать на чистом JavaScript без проверки на сервере так же не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0):

сталкивался с подобным. очень может быть, что motionCaptcha не работает на 1.7 версии.

зыж подключать 2 jquery вообще плохая затея. не выйдет ничего из этого хорошего.
ззыж смотрите ошибки в консоли. оно НЕ будет работать, потому что сначала вы подключаете 1.6.2, потом к НЕМУ подключаете капчу, которая его использует, а потом вы УДАЛЯЕТЕ jquery и подключаете ДРУГОЙ jquery...

**дурацкий пример:** вы встали на стул, чтобы поменять лампочку, не слезая со стула вы меняете стул на другой -- результат -- вы падаете ;)

Answer (score 0):

Скрипт (плагин) не совместим с jQuery 1.7. Тогда прийдётся смириться с более старой версией jQuery илит искать другой плагин.

Для уточнения: Вы же заменяете эти строчки, а не добавляете к старой?